# what is sqlserver database remark returned fom sp_databases?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2000

The sp_databases stored proc in sqlserver returns a remarks column.  Where does this information come from, and can I edit it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This field always retuns null.  You can not edit it, unless you modify the system stored procedure which is not recommended.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259636(SQL.80).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Simply run `sp_helptext sp_databases` and you'll see:

```
REMARKS   = convert(varchar(254),null)
```

It's a brand new NULL, manufactured just in time, for your convenience.